# Script to move or unpack files (rtorrent when finished script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, rtorrent

**The concept**

So I´ve been struggling for a while now with a script that will run when rtorrent has finished a download. The script should check the third argument from rtorrent and act accordingly.

.rtorrent.rc:

```
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,unrar_move_files,"execute={/home/holmen/script/testrt.sh,$d.get_base_path=,$d.get_name=,$d.get_custom1=}"
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# First, copy the downloaded material to the storage drive
# then unpack the files (if the unrar returned successful)
# lastly remove the rar files with rm -rfv command

hdfilm1=/media/store1/HD-film
hdfilm2=/media/store2/HD-film
download=/media/store3/Download

# Copy the downloaded material to correct storage drive
rsync -r --info=progress2 "$download"/"$2" "$3"

if [ "$3" = "$hdfilm1" ] || [ "$3" = "$hdfilm2" ]; then
        # Check folders and subfolders of the downloaded material
        while IFS= read -r dir; do
                # Find and unpack archive files
                if [ "$(find $dir | egrep -i '\.r00|\.001|part01\.rar|part001\.rar|subs\.rar')" ]; then
                        rarFile=`ls $dir | egrep -i '\.r00|\.001|part01\.rar|part001\.rar|subs\.rar'`;
                        searchPath="$dir/$rarFile"
                        yes no | nice -n 15 unrar x -o+ "$searchPath" "$dir"
                        remFile=`ls $dir | egrep -i '\.(rar|sfv|r([0-9]{2}))$'`;
                        remPath="$dir/$remFile"
                        rm -rfv $remPath
                fi
        done < <(find "$3"/"$2" -type d)
fi
```

This works basically but i have trouble when trying to delete the archive files (after they are unpacked). When adding a remove script in the `while` loop the script just removes files in the specific subfolder its in at the moment.

The script unpacks:

```
/media/store1/HD-film/Movie.folder/*.rar
/media/store1/HD-film/Movie.folder/Subs/*.rar
```

but only removes the rar files in this folder

```
/media/store1/HD-film/Movie.folder/Subs/
```

How can I fix so my script removes the archive files also in the parent folder?

**Edit:** I have tried putting the `rm` command after the unrar command with `&&` but the result is the same.

```
if [ "$(find $dir | egrep -i '\.r00|\.001|part01\.rar|part001\.rar|subs\.rar')" ]; then
     rarFile=`ls $dir | egrep -i '\.r00|\.001|part01\.rar|part001\.rar|subs\.rar'`;
     searchPath="$dir/$rarFile"
     remFile=`ls $dir | egrep -i '\.(rar|sfv|r([0-9]{2}))$'`;
     remove="$dir/$remFile"
     yes no | nice -n 15 unrar x -o+ "$searchPath" "$dir" && rm -rfv "$remove"
fi
```

Comment: How do you try to remove rar files? It would be better to include that in the posted code.

Comment: I added this code to the if section of the while loop: remFile=` ls $dir | egrep -i '\.[r|s|0-9][a|f|0-9][r|v|0-9]$'`; remPath="$dir/$remFile"; rm -rfv $remPath

Comment: It would be better to edit that into your question

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem with this script [unrarall](https://github.com/arfoll/unrarall). I've implemented it in my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
hdfilm1=/media/store1/HD-film
hdfilm2=/media/store2/HD-film
tvshow1=/media/store0/Serier
tvshow2=/media/store2/Serier
download=/media/store3/Download

# Copy the downloaded material to correct storage drive
rsync -r --info=progress2 "$download"/"$2" "$3"

if [ "$3" = "$hdfilm1" ] || [ "$3" = "$hdfilm2" ] || [ "$3" = "$tvshow1" ] || [ "$3" = "$tvshow2" ]; then
        /home/holmen/script/unrarall --clean=rar,proof_folders,sample_folders,sample_videos,empty_folders "$3"/"$2"
fi
```